# How to increment LAG offset argument within loop?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to use the `LAG()` function within a loop where the second argument, `offset`, is incremented with each iteration as in the following:

```sql
BEGIN

  DECLARE i INT64 DEFAULT 1;

  WHILE i < 6 DO

    SELECT
      col1_cat
      ,col2_ts
      ,col3_val
      ,LAG(col3_val, i) OVER(PARTITION BY col1_cat ORDER BY col2_ts DESC) AS col3_val_lag1
    FROM
      my_table;

    SET i = i + 1;

  END WHILE;

END;
```

Unfortunately, docs and error make clear that

> Argument 2 to LAG must be a literal or query parameter

**How can I accomplish this task while avoiding this error?**

Comment: what your goal here? what result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to analyze the distribution of diffs in values over n different lags.

Comment: I meant - what you are trying to get out of your script? As it is now - it does nothing even if variables were supported in LAG's OFFSET

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it does nothing"? Were variables supported in LAG's offset arg, it would definitely do *something*. That said, my intention is part of a larger script not relevant to this question. Here I have isolated certain logic in order to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: as I said  - the logic you presented does nothing, thus it is hard to understand what it is that you are targeting - so no way to help you with workaround, which certainly exists but can differ depends on those not "relevant" details :o)

Comment: What do you mean "it does nothing"? You're not being particularly helpful with these comments. Please elaborate. Do you mean you don't understand how different values would be returned as `offset` is incremented? As I've said, the larger context of the script from which this logic is extracted is irrelevant to an MRE.

Answer (score 2):

Try below

```
BEGIN

  DECLARE i INT64 DEFAULT 1;

  WHILE i < 6 DO

    SELECT
      col1_cat
      ,col2_ts
      ,col3_val
      ,ARRAY_REVERSE(ARRAY_AGG(col3_val) OVER(PARTITION BY col1_cat ORDER BY col2_ts DESC))[SAFE_OFFSET(i)] AS col3_val_lag1 
    FROM
      my_table;

    SET i = i + 1;

  END WHILE;

END;
```